# What is exactly the difference between <1-> and <1> in Beamer?

Tags: beamer, overlays

In `beamer`, I used

```
\visible<1->
\visible<2->
```

To display one text after the other, and

```
\only<1>
\only<2>
```

to show one text at a time

Can I exchange `<1>` with `<1->`? Can I do `<-1>`, `<-2>`?

What are some other commands that use this arrow/bracket symbol?

What are some convention or rule with using this symbol?

Comment: `\only<1>` means "only on frame 1", `\only<1-3>` means "only on frames 1,2,3" and `\only<2->` "only on all frames 2,3,...".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the [`beamer`](//ctan.org/pkg/beamer) [user guide](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf), section **3.10 Using Overlay Specifications**:

> ```
> \begin{frame}
>   \frametitle{There Is No Largest Prime Number}
>   \framesubtitle{The proof uses \textit{reductio ad absurdum}.}
>   \begin{theorem}
>     There is no largest prime number.
>   \end{theorem}
>   \begin{proof}
>     \begin{enumerate}
>       \item<1-> Suppose $p$ were the largest prime number.
>       \item<2-> Let $q$ be the product of the first $p$ numbers.
>       \item<3-> Then $q + 1$ is not divisible by any of them.
>       \item<1-> But $q + 1$ is greater than $1$, thus divisible by some prime
>         number not in the first $p$ numbers.\qedhere
>     \end{enumerate}
>   \end{proof}
>   \uncover<4->{The proof used \textit{reductio ad absurdum}.}
> \end{frame}
> ```
>
> The overlay specifications are given in pointed brackets. The specification `<1->` means "from slide 1 on." Thus, the first and fourth item are shown on the first slide of the frame, but the other two items are not shown. Rather, the second point is shown only from the second slide onward. `beamer` automatically computes the number of slides needed for each frame. More generally, overlay specification are lists of numbers or number ranges where the start or ending of a range can be left open. For example `-3,5-6,8-` means "on all slides, except for slides 4 and 7."

So, `<1>` is different from `<1->`, but similar to `<-1>` (since there is no zeroth slide). `<-2>` would be all slides up to the second.

There are a number of environments and commands in the `beamer` class that accepts overlay specifications. You can browse through part **II Building a Presentation** and section **9.3 Commands with Overlay Specifications** of the documentation. It lists the typical presentation environments and commands and their overlay specification.

> The command `\only`, which is introduced by `beamer`, normally simply inserts its parameter into the current frame. However, if an overlay specification is present, it "throws away" its parameter on slides that are not mentioned.
>
> Overlay specifications can only be written behind certain commands, not every command. Which commands you can use and which effects this will have is explained in the next section. However, it is quite easy to redefine an existing command such that it becomes "overlay specification aware," see also Section 9.3.
>
> The syntax of (basic) overlay specifications is the following: They are comma-separated lists of slides and ranges. Ranges are specified like this: `2-5`, which means slide two through to five. The start or the end of a range can be omitted. For example, `3-` means "slides three, four, five, and so on" and `-5` means the same as `1-5`. A complicated example is `-3,6-8,10,12-15`, which selects the slides 1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 8, 10, 12, 13, 14, and 15.